# What would happen if undocumented immigrants vote in the United States?

Tags: united-states, elections

Asking this as a factual question. No political agenda intended.

In the current US election dispute team Trump have repeatedly made the allegation that there was mass voting by undocumented immigrants. (They use the term "illegals")

If that is true at all, would their votes actually be disqualified? Or are they lawfully entitled to vote while they are living in the USA?

Just inform me about the law, please. No arguing about whether the law as it stands it is right or wrong, or whether the claim is true or not, or whether it would change the result.

Comment: https://www.usa.gov/who-can-vote, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_of_foreigners_to_vote_in_the_United_States.

Comment: I doubt there are many places where people with no legal right to be there can legally help to decide who gets to run the country (or legally do much of anything, for that matter).

Comment: @NotThatGuy California and some other states let them get driver's licenses. https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-undocumented-person-california-drivers-license.html (responding to "or legally do much of anything")

Comment: @NotThatGuy Germany distinguishes between "resident" and "legal resident". Being a resident, even if illegal, gives you certain rights and duties (for example the duty to pay income tax on your income, and the right and duty to send your kids to school). Obviously making yourself known to authorities can cause you trouble if you are a resident, but not a legal resident.

Comment: I wonder how difficult it is to vote. I would assume that if I walked into a poll station on election date and said "Here's my German passport, can I vote please?" they would just say "Sorry mate, US citizens only today." and send me home.

Comment: They are illegal immigrants because they did not emigrate into the United States legally. My father emigrated to the United States legally through a set port, with documentation, health and country, as well as documenting who was his sponsor, e.g. responsible for his well-being should he be unable to work or require medical care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[18 U.S. Code § 611](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/611) is the relevant law.

> (a) It shall be unlawful for any alien to vote in any election held
> solely or in part for the purpose of electing a candidate for the
> office of President, Vice President, Presidential elector, Member of
> the Senate, Member of the House of Representatives, Delegate from the
> District of Columbia, or Resident Commissioner, unless— (1) the
> election is held partly for some other purpose; (2) aliens are
> authorized to vote for such other purpose under a State constitution
> or statute or a local ordinance; and (3) voting for such other purpose
> is conducted independently of voting for a candidate for such Federal
> offices, in such a manner that an alien has the opportunity to vote
> for such other purpose, but not an opportunity to vote for a candidate
> for any one or more of such Federal offices.

This is not the most straightforward of law on the books. It says "you can't vote unless..." three things. It has to be locally legal to vote for something other than a federal office, the election has to include something other than voting for federal office, and it cannot be possible to vote for a federal office at the same time. Given that, it is impossible for any alien (even documented) to vote for president. Extant alien-voting laws are no higher than municipality, most being in Maryland. Violation of the law is a crime.

Because non-citizens are not allowed to vote in state-wide elections, the theory is that they literally cannot vote, so they will not receive a ballot, which comes from the state. [Here](https://elections.maryland.gov/laws_and_regs/documents/Election%20Law%202011.pdf) are the election laws for Maryland. There isn't a provision for "disqualifying" a vote, instead a person is prevented from voting in the first place if they are successfully challenged, because they can't prove who they are or the person they claim to be is not registered to vote (a non-citizen will never be registered with the state to vote, assuming no fraudulent documentation). Takoma Park non-citizen residents can vote in city elections and they register with the local gov't, not the state.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. You say: <<There isn't a provision for "disqualifying" a vote>>  Just to be clear, that means the point is moot? If the claim is true and can be proved, it wouldn't alter the results?

Comment: @Pete for an explanation of why the vote totals cannot be altered, see my answer.

Comment: I do think if it were proven to be true, it's possible SCOTUS could order some remedy that isn't anticipated in the statutes; but we'd be in the land of extreme speculation. The procedure is basically, "once you're through the gate, the vote goes into a big unlabelled bin", although in some states like Washington, the ballot form has an identifier where a person's identity can be correlated. RCW Ch. 29a.04 simply says the SOS "shall make rules", and does not say "cannot include voter barcode".

Comment: By "impossible" I think you actually meant "impermissible".  Just a few ways the impermissible might be possible: (a) bad registration data, for example transferring driver's license application data to the voter registration system without properly filtering out non-citizens  (b) gaining physical possession of a legitimate voter's mail in ballot, (c) using the identity of a legitimate voter to vote in person.  These may be *improbable* but they are not physically impossible.

Comment: @BenVoigt "transferring driver's license application data to the voter registration system without properly filtering out non-citizens" this is known to have happened in NY, but is not believed to have happened in significant numbers.

Comment: @Ryan_L: Even one counterexample is sufficient to disprove a universal claim such as "impossible" (other forms of proof exist that don't require examples, but a false-by-counterexample proof is easy to follow)

Comment: @user6726 the statute section you reference is a huge section of text. At what specific point does it allow for breaking the secret ballot rule? Any way to go back from ballot to voter makes the vote non-secret.

Comment: For what it is wroth, one area where non-citizens can often vote is in governmental special taxing district elections which often allow all property owners with property in the taxing district to vote. Typically, a special taxing district would provide some sort of local utility-like service, such as water or sewer services in territory outside of an incorporated municipal government.

Answer (score 6):

As [another answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58886/what-would-happen-if-undocumented-immigrants-vote-in-the-united-states#answer-58889) points out, no alien is permitted to vote in a federal election, whether undocumented or otherwise.  There are other reasons for ineligibility, of course: people who aren't yet 18 years old are unable to vote, as are convicted felons in most cases.

As to what happens in such cases, you can look at the case of Rosa Maria Ortega, who was a lawful permanent resident of the US (that is, she had a green card).  She was convicted under Texas law for voting (for Republican candidates, including for the attorney general who prosecuted her).  She faces loss of her permanent resident status and deportation to Mexico even though she lived in the US from infancy.

(Source: https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2020/02/21/rosa-maria-ortega-texas-woman-sentenced-8-years-illegal-voting-paroled-and-faces-deportation/4798922002/)

There is no suggestion that this development caused the vote counts to be revised.  Indeed, because of the secret ballot, having such a provision would be an invitation to further fraud.  Consider the following hypothetical:

1. In an election with two candidates, the winning candidate Alice received 200 more votes than the losing candidate Bob, but 300 votes have been cast by ineligible voters.  For the sake of illustration, assume that the totals are 1200 votes for Alice and 1000 votes for Bob.
2. The 300 ineligible voters all voted for Alice, so invalidating their votes should change the result of the election to a victory by Bob of 100 votes (that is, Bob wins with 1000 votes against Alice's 900).
3. However, the ballots being secret, the only way know who anyone voted for is to ask.  When asked, the 300 ineligible voters all say that they voted for Bob.  As a result, the vote totals are revised in Alice's favor, leaving a total of 1200 votes for Alice and 700 votes for Bob, a margin of 500 for Alice.

This should explain why, given a secret ballot, not only *is* there no provision for disqualifying votes, but there *cannot be* such a provision.

Comment: Thank you, that is also a helpful answer.

Comment: This "victory by Bob, that is, Alice wins" makes no sense in bullet #2.  I think you have a typo there.

Comment: Not all convicted felons can't vote

Comment: It was once the case that all, or almost all, US state denied convicted felons the right to vote.  Now most states do this only for a few specific crimes, notably election fraud.

Comment: The numbers in the example with Alice and Bob seem to be mixed up or incorrect in several places. Please fix or remove them.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks. The confusion actually began in the first bullet point.  I've fixed it.  (I hope.)

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- correct. I will add a weasel word.

Comment: @DavidSiegel done, thanks.

Comment: @DavidSiegel as far as I can see all states except Maine and Vermont disenfranchise all felons regardless of the nature of the crime.  Are you referring to the restoration of voting rights after the sentence has been served?

Comment: @phoog, no I was not, but I may be mistaken. This is probably worth a separate question and answer.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Here's the map I used to check my statement: https://www.aclu.org/issues/voting-rights/voter-restoration/felony-disenfranchisement-laws-map I think you're referring to the orange/yellow category (six states), definitely not "most states" But this is far from my area of expertise

Comment: @Azor Ahai  I was basing my statement on a memory of something I read about changes in such laws several years ago. It looks as if my memory or source was incorrect. The closest match on the linked map is the blue, blue-stripped, and orange/yellow sections taken together (21 states if i counted correctly), but none quite match my memory. I belive that it was once the case that all states denied felons the right to vote forever. This seems now the case in only 3 states.

Comment: Any information what Mrs. Ortega had to do to actually vote? I would have thought that she would have been stopped from actually voting somehow.

Comment: @gnasher729 either she was not required to show ID (as is the case in many states) or else she probably showed her driver's license (which, although it is not proof of citizenship, is accepted as voter ID in states that require it).  The facts of the case are presented in linked article after the sentence "Her indictment in November 2015 followed a series of actions she revealed to elections officials and law enforcement investigators."  It doesn't explain how she voted in Dallas county, but she probably claimed US citizenship at some point, perhaps unknowingly.

Comment: @gnasher729 she might have been registered incorrectly when applying for a driver's license, either because of an administrative error (apparently not uncommon) or because she requested registration by mistake. Voter ID laws typically don't require proof of citizenship, only proof of identification, for which a driver's license is sufficient. Many wrongly believe that green-card holders can vote, or even that they are US citizens. Once registered, the only way she would have been stopped would have been her lack of US citizenship coming to light, which happened, though too late to help her.

Answer (score 2):

Only citizens are allowed to vote in federal elections, so undocumented immigrants are not allowed to vote. Other people (felons, etc.) may also be prohibited from voting depending on state law.

The details of what happens depend on the state, but as a general thing:

In-person voting by someone identified as being on the list of eligible voters who haven't voted already: The fact that you voted will be recorded in a separate step from you actually voting. Your actual vote doesn't have your name on it so it *is not* possible to discard your ballot after it is cast.

In-person voting by someone not identified as being on the list of eligible voters: Even if you aren't on the list of eligible voters you can typically still cast a provisional ballot (this is federal law for federal elections). These ballots are kept separate with the identification of the voter attached to each one and they are only counted if the voter is found to be eligible. Otherwise they *are* discarded.

Mail voting if the outer envelope is intact: The ballot goes in an outer envelope that has your identification on it. Ballots *are* discarded if the voter is discovered to be ineligible (even if the voter was eligible when they mailed the ballot--there have been cases where the voter died between mailing the ballot and it being opened). This is one reason why some states only open mail ballots starting on the day of the election.

Mail voting after the outer envelope is removed: Usually there is an inner envelope which protects the privacy of the ballot. Once the inner envelope or ballot is separated from the outer envelope then the ballot no longer has your name on it and *can not* be discarded.

For all voting, if it is discovered that you cast or attempted to cast a vote while ineligible then you will be in serious legal trouble. Even if it was discovered before your vote was counted and instead your ballot was discarded. Even if you didn't realize that you were ineligible. For mail votes this generally applies to the time when you mailed it.