# Have the "alternate elelectors" committed a crime?

Tags: united-states, elections

Trying to vote in an election without a legal right to do so is a crime.  One person in the 2020 US Presidential election [was caught trying to use his dead mother's vote](https://www.businessinsider.com/voter-election-fraud-pennsylvania-charge-dead-mom-vote-trump-2020-12?r=US&IR=T), and now faces up to 19 years in prison.  In [another question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58886/what-would-happen-if-undocumented-immigrants-vote-in-the-united-states) on this forum I learned about Rosa Maria Ortega, a resident alien who voted illegally, and got an 8 year sentence, plus possible deportation.

In several States various self-appointed group of people have declared themselves to be "alternate electors."  They have tried to cast Electoral College votes for Trump, which they sent to Congress for counting on Jan 6th.

Have they actually committed a crime under Election law?

Would this count as Sedition?

Is it likely they will be prosecuted?

Comment: Nice try, Donald. Is this what you have come to?